# Why does $\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}P(A_{\infty}\geq c^{2})dc=E[\int\limits_{0}^{\sqrt{A_{\infty}}}dc+\int\limits_{0}^{\sqrt{A_{\infty}}}dc]$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, probability-theory, expected-value

Why does $\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}P(A_{\infty}\geq c^{2})dc=E[\int\limits_{0}^{\sqrt{A_{\infty}}}dc+\int\limits_{0}^{\sqrt{A_{\infty}}}dc]$?

My attempt: $A_{\infty}\geq c^{2}\iff \sqrt{A_{\infty}} \geq c \text{ or }-\sqrt{A_{\infty}} \geq c$ and thus $P(A_{\infty}\geq c^{2})=P(\sqrt{A_{\infty}} \geq c)+P(-\sqrt{A_{\infty}} \geq c)$, therefore using Fubini, we get:

$$\int _{0}^{\infty}P(A_{\infty}\geq c^{2})dc=\int _{0}^{\infty}P(\sqrt{A_{\infty}} \geq c)dc+\int _{0}^{\infty}P(-\sqrt{A_{\infty}} \geq c)dc$$

For the first term it is clear that $\int _{0}^{\infty}P(\sqrt{A_{\infty}} \geq c)dc = E[\int\limits_{0}^{\sqrt{A_{\infty}}}dc]$

But if I do the same Fubini trick for the term, I would get $\int _{0}^{\infty}P(-\sqrt{A_{\infty}} \geq c)dc=E[\int\limits_{0}^{-\sqrt{A_{\infty}}}dc]$

And this would then lead to $$\int _{0}^{\infty}P(A_{\infty}\geq c^{2})dc=0$$ which seems very wrong. Any idea on where I am going wrong?

Comment: You are wrong in "$A_\infty \geq c^2\iff \sqrt{A_\infty}\geq c\text{ or } -\sqrt{A_\infty}\geq c$". The correct affirmation is "$A_\infty \geq c^2\iff \sqrt{A_\infty}\geq c\geq -\sqrt{A_\infty}$"